# How to allocate constants in the function to the desired address?

Tags: c, linker, embedded, ld

I'm working on a project for an embedded device, that uses the custom `ld` script. I'm using [GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain version 5-2016](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads/5-2016-q3-update).

In the linker script, I define a custom section located on the specific address. Here is an abbreviated example:

```
MEMORY
{
    FLASH (RX)   : ORIGIN = 0x8000000, LENGTH = 1M
}

SECTIONS
{
  .mysection :
  {
    __mysection_start__ = .;
    *(.mysection*)
    *(.mysection)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    __mysection_end__ = .;
  } > FLASH
}
```

In the code I use `__attribute__(section("mysection"))` to locate the specific functions in the custom section. Consider at the following example:

```c
void foo1()
{
    const char str[] = "foo1_string";
}

void foo2() __attribute__((section("mysection")));
void foo2()
{
    const char str[] = "foo2_string";
}
```

In this example I expect that the string literal `str` defined in the function `foo2` will be located in the `mysection` section, however, it falls in the `.rodata` section.

What the correct way to allocate the constants from the `foo2` function to the `mysection` section? Is it possible to do this without adding an attribute `section` to each variable inside the function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the attribute on the thing that you want to locate, on the variable not the containing function.

Comment: @TomV Yes, I'm aware this is possible. But the problem is that I have a lot of these variables. I'm wondering, is there a way to add all constants from the function without adding attributes to each of them?

Comment: Another problem is anonymous string literals in the function calls. For example `printf("hello");` in my function will save the string `"hello"` to `.rodata`.

Comment: How else would you like to tell the linker which variable it has to put in what section? You need the attribute at all variables that belong to non-default sections.

Comment: @thebusybee I do not know, I did not find anything similar in the manual. I think this is a fairly common problem, maybe there are ways to solve it more elegantly. But if not, I'll have to add attributes.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't want the string literals to live in .rodata?

Comment: You could just have a macro to define string literals and put them in a specific section

Comment: @lulle I need to keep the `.rodata` with some other data separately, on the specific partition. This is a requirement for the project, I can't do anything about it.

Comment: I can see why you might want this but I don't think the compiler supports it, sorry.

Comment: The limit would be in the linker script. Try the solution in my answer and see if it works, or if it still generates string literals in .rodata as duplicates. Other embedded system linkers have the option to re-direct .rodata etc to whatever location you want, but I'm not entirely sure about gcc.

Comment: Did you check the section where string literals actually go? I remember that `.rodata` is a collection of multiple subsections like `.rodata.str` or so. If this happens to be the case, you can locate this subsection anywhere else. Investigate your linker map.

Comment: @thebusybee Yes, I did. The linker creates subsections for each variable as you describe it. But I actually solved this problem as 0___________ suggested. I've created the separate object files with `.rodata` that should be placed in the other section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the .rodata section data, from the particular object file(s) into another section

```
SECTIONS
{
  .mysection :
  {
    __mysection_start__ = .;
    *(.mysection*)
    *(.mysection)
    *myfile.o(.rodata)
    *myfile.o(.rodata*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    __mysection_end__ = .;
  } > FLASH
}
```

In this example all data from the `myfile.o` (usually it will be result of the myfile.c compilation) which is in section `.rodata` (including string literals) will be placed in the `.mysection`. You can also use wildcards in the file names.

I think it will sort out your problem.

`__attribute__((section("mysection")));` is incorrect . It has to be `__attribute__((section(".mysection")));` because the name of your section is `.mysection`

Comment: Thank you very much! This actually solves my problem. The missing `.` in the section name was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please note that everything in your program has a default location as per [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/237759/6102). That's what applies unless you specifically tell it otherwise. For a function, that typically means that the function itself ends up in `.text`, a local variable inside the function in `.stack` and a string literal used by the function in `.rodata`. By allocating the function in a different section, that doesn't mean that those items inside the function somehow change location as well.

`__attribute__((section...` is similar to storage-class specifiers or type qualifiers (`static`, `const` etc) since it belongs with the object or function you place it next to. So you'll have to do:

```
static const char str[] __attribute__((section("mysection"))) = "foo1_string";
```

`static` since this is a local variable to the function. Without it, it has automatic storage duration and then compilers might be tempted to store that variable in RAM rather than flash. Also, in case you initialize local RAM variables to a string literal, that string literal will have to be allocated separately in flash, in .rodata or similar.

Since you seem to want to change the location of string literals only, then you shouldn't add `__attribute__((section...` to the function, only to invividual variables. You may have to do this to every single instance of your program where a string literal exists.

Make sure to check the map file to see that everything ended up where you expected it.

Comment: I think that it does not the problem : `"How to place string literals in my section"`

Comment: @0___________ I realize that, but my assumption is that the compiler should be smart enough not to allocate a duplicate of it in `.rodata` if you allocate it in flash/static storage duration. Because you don't need to perform a "copy down" from flash to RAM then, as you would if it was a local array initialized with a string literal.

Comment: Compiler will not not. OP uses auto variables which are initialized **runtime** using string literals. Those string literals have to be stored somewhere and they are in .rodata. If variables have static storage duration there will not be any duplication. But it is not the case here

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the good explanation at the link. Marking each variable with an `__attribute__(section)` is another good alternative, but for my particular use case, it's easier to use different object files as 0___________ suggested.